# SQLite: Should I use Integer primary key or Integer when storing data from API?

Tags: ios, sqlite, integer, primary-key

I've inherited an iOS project that stores record ids in a column using the data type `Integer primary key`.  This works well, however, I'm not sure why it isn't just using regular `Integer`. The iOS App grabs records from an API and stores it in the local SQLite database. These records from the API each have a unique id already (e.g. id:100101394).

Is there a reason or an advantage in using Integer primary key over regular integer in this situation?

Edit: The app uses the record's unique id for the Integer primary key if that makes sense, but I don't know why I can't just use a regular integer.

Edit 1: Everyone, I understand I can use a primary key to access records. What I want to understand is if there is a reason why I should use it over a regular Integer that I can store the record's id in. Each record id the API returns is unique.

Comment: A reason? Smaller tables (Since it's an alias for the rowid value that's the row's *real* PK it doesn't take up extra space like a normal column), and faster lookups by id (Even if you have an index on a non-PK INTEGER column).

Comment: To make sure I understand correctly. The two advantages are doesn't make the table bigger and it is faster to look up a primary key then it is an integer. Sorry, but I want to be sure since I am a bit new to all of this.

Comment: A PK that's not a single INTEGER column is just a normal unique index in sqlite. Read the link about rowids in one of the answers, and [this description](https://sqlite.org/queryplanner.html) of how sqlite uses indexes to help understand how it works. Basically, if you look up a row by rowid/integer primary key, the row can be found directly without any secondary lookups like other indexed columns require. (And, of course, looking up an unindexed column requires a full table scan of every single row).

Comment: Okay, I'm kind of getting it. However, I have one concern. So in my example, if an API returns records with a unique id already for example 100. Then, I store that id (100) as the primary key. If I look up by primary key, will it still be found directly or will it do a full table scan? I apologize if I'm frustrating you, I just need to be sure because I assumed something before and caused me a lot of issues in the past.

Comment: Read that link in my other comment.

Comment: Okay, I see, so it does find it directly. So overall, storing the record's id from the API as a primary key is a good idea. Not only can I search directly, but it creates a smaller table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer Primary Key is typed, you can only put in an integer.  It also will guarantee an integer is inserted when null is put in.  I believe it can also act as an alias as RowID If that exists for the table.

Here is a link to the documentation on it.

https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid

Answer (score 0):

I believe you use a key when you expect to want to find the record by that identifier. I would expect that to impose additional overhead when storing the item, but if you want to access a record by the 'integer primary key' id, you can potentially save a lot of time and system overhead.